# Excel: Chart Event times for teams

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a dataset that looks like below:

```
Team    Start   End     Days
1       5/22/18 8/13/18 83
2       5/24/18 6/30/18 37
1       5/28/18 7/10/18 43
2       6/4/18  8/10/18 67
3       6/6/18  6/26/18 20
4       6/16/18 7/6/18  20
5       6/20/18 6/29/18 9
1       6/20/18 6/29/18 9
3       6/23/18 6/26/18 3
```

How can I chart a histogram type chart with the percentage of each team missing per day in excel? I am unable to use VBA for this.

Comment: You received an answer that appears to meet your needs, but this question isn't clear for other readers or other potential answerers.  What does "percentage of each team missing per day" mean, and how do you get that from the data you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns `A:D`, start a new table as so:

```
+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
|    G    | H | I | J | K | L |
+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
|         | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5/22/18 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 5/23/18 |   |   |   |   |   |
| 5/24/18 |   |   |   |   |   |
| ...     |   |   |   |   |   |
+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Populate it with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,"<="&$G2,$C$2:$C$6,">="&$G2,$A$2:$A$6,H$1)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,H$1)
```

Then generate a chart from this table

Note: I assumed that all members of a team are listed in the data table (so in you  sample data, team 1 has 3 members and so on)